Find files that are sorted before a given file
I have a directory with a number of files.
Example:
aaa.txt
bbb.txt
ccc.txt
ddd.txt

Given an arbitrary string (not necessarily the name of one of the files), I want to find all the files that are sorted before that string (in a normal alphabetical sort).
Example: Give ccc.txt I want to find bbb.txt and aaa.txt.
The file names only contain normal ASCII characters. LC_ALL=C can be assumed. There are no hidden files (starting with .).
A potential solution could be something like this (with a made up test):
$ find -isnamelessthan ccc.txt
aaa.txt
bbb.txt

How can this be done?

LC_ALL=C also affects the order for ASCII characters. For instance, in English locales at least, abc comes before DEF, but with LC_ALL=C, that's the reverse.

If the test utility on your system supports the non-standard < operator for determining whether a string sorts before another string, then you may use this with find:
find . -exec test {} '<' ./ccc.txt \; -print

or,
find . -exec [ {} '<' ./ccc.txt ] \; -print

Here, I'm comparing using the file's pathname relative to the current directory because that's how the other pathnames will look, too.  Note that the < operator needs to be quoted as '<', "<" or \<, to prevent the shell from interpreting it as a redirection operator.
If the test succeeds, the -print predicate will cause the pathname to be outputted.
Add further tests to e.g. limit the search to only regular files, avoid descending into subdirectories, and avoid hidden names (or whatever other conditions you may come up with):
find . ! -path . -prune ! -name '.*' -type f -exec [ {} '<' ./ccc.txt ] \; -print


Ah, didn't know you could do that with -exec! I think this is better than the solutions using awk.

With zsh:
print -rC1 -- **/*(NDe['[[ $REPLY:t < ccc.txt ]]'])

Where:

print -rC1 -- prints its arguments raw and on 1 Column
**/ matches any level of subdirectories (including 0) for a recursive search like find does.
(...) are glob qualifiers to further qualify the match:

N: nullglob so as not to report an error (and print to print nothing) if there's no match:
D: dotglob like with find, don't exclude hidden files
e['code']: run the code to see if the file should be selected. Here the code is [[ $REPLY:t < ccc.txt ]] which compares lexically (using memcmp(),  not the locale-aware strcoll() function¹) the tail (basename) of $REPLY (the file path being considered) with ccc.txt.



On a GNU system, you could do something similar (in any shell) with:
find . -mindepth 1 -printf '%P\0' | sort -z |
  LC_ALL=C gawk -v RS='\0' -F/ '$NF < "ccc.txt"'

Where:

-mindepth 1, excludes the starting file (.). You could also use the standard ! -name ., though that couldn't be extended to other starting files².
-printf '%P\0' prints the path of the files relative to the starting file, so for instance dir/aaa.txt for ./dir/a.txt, delimited by a NUL bytes (the only byte value that cannot occur in a file path).
sort -z sorts the list according to strcoll() as ls/globs do.
LC_ALL=C turns strcoll() (as used by awk's <) into memcmp() (on ASCII-based systems)
-v RS='\0' sets the input Record Separator to the NUL byte (the ORS remains the default of newline)
-F/, short for -v FS=/ sets the Field Separator to /.
$NF < "ccc.txt": compares the last field with "ccc.txt" lexically, and if that's true, the default action ({print}, short for {print $0}) is run which prints the record.

For a -isnamelessthan find predicate, you could do (in zsh):
alias -g -- -isnamelessthan='-exec zsh -c "[[ \$1:t < \$2 ]]" zsh {}'

To be used as:
find . -isnamelessthan ccc.txt ';' -print

(not efficient as it runs an instance of zsh to check each file).

¹ while the globs themselves are sorted as per the locale, so using strcoll()
² While you can't do find /path/to/dir ! -name dir as that would exclude files also called dir within, you can do find /path/to/dir/. ! -name . though.

This is a nice answer! But I don't use Zsh. :(

@Lii from another shell, you can always do zsh -c "that-code".

Assuming your file names don't contain newlines then using any awk:
$ printf '%s\n' * | awk '$0 >= "ccc.txt"{exit} 1'
aaa.txt
bbb.txt


Stéphane Chazelas and Ed Morton have posted good answers using gawk and awk, that seem to solve the problem elegantly in a single line.
However, future programmers have to know awk to understand those solutions in detail. Because of this I think it's better in my case to use a simple for-loop.
I will accept Stéphane's answer because it has the best explanation, but leave my own solution here as well.
target="ccc.txt"
arr=()

target="ccc.txt"
arr=()

for f in * ; do
    # You can compare all string (also non-numeric) using <
    # -f handles the case when there are no files present
    if [[ -f $f && $f < $target ]] ; then arr+=("$f") ; fi
done

echo ${arr[@]}


You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issue(s) it'll tell you about. It'd be far more efficient if you broke out of the loop when $f < $target fails.

I would create a simple function like this:
names_less_than() {
    search_escaped=$(printf "%s\n" "$1" | sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g')
    (ls -A -- "$2"; printf "%s\n" "$1") | sort | sed -n "/^${search_escaped}$/q;p"
}

First argument is the input string, the second argument is the target directory.
Note this will break if you have files that contain newlines in the names. If you are using GNU ls, then you can add the -b flag to escape certain characters such as newlines.
The sed regex escape is from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573

@EdMorton I specifically added the printf so that this is not the case. I just did another quick test and I can confirm that the file does not need to exist.

I assume that the input is sorted and there is one file per line.
If you know that this is true for you and if ccc.txt is in the output, you could use sed:
$ ls | sed -n '/ccc.txt/q;p'
aaa.txt
bbb.txt


/ccc.txt/ matches on a line that contains ccc, a single character and txt. For instance, it matches on aaacccbtxt.html.

ls output is already sorted, so you don't need to pipe to sort. Also note that when not going to a terminal, the output of ls is on one column already, so the -1 is superfluous.

You don't need to call sed twice, you could do ls -A | sed -n '/^ccc\.txt$/q;p' (also addressing the two issues above and not excluding hidden files, not the issue with filenames containing characters, not looking for files in subdirectories as find does and still assuming ccc.txt is among the list of files).

I don't think we can assume that ccc.txt will exist either. My understanding of the question, which may be wrong of course, is that the OP wants a way to say "show me file names that sort before X" but the X doesn't need to also exist as a file name.

@terdon: ""show me file names that sort before X" Yes, exactly, thank you!

@StéphaneChazelas: "not excluding hidden files" I added a note to the question that there are no hidden files.

@ctx: Thanks for the suggestion, but as terdon notes ccc.txt it not necessarily one of the files, maybe I should make this more clear from the text. Clever use of /q though, I didn't know about that one.

That would stop at a file name like ccc+txt (which may sort before ccc.txt) or aaaccc.txtbbb. If you're going to use sed for this then you need to escape any regexp metachars in the regexp since sed doesn't understand literal strings, see is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed, and add start+end of string anchors.

Hmmm. ctx says you shouldn't parse the output of ls - but OP never said the list of files came from ls. ctx never said why you shouldn't parse the output of ls. ctx goes on to parse the output of ls. Am I the only one who is confused by this?

@EdMorton: I agree that the question isn't as clear as it could be on this. But the text does say "Given an arbitrary string...", so a careful reader will be able to understand. But I will make the text more clear!

I wanted to add a simple solution for the case that the file names are known and exactly follow the pattern from OP.
